# Optional Input and Workspace in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

1 - I am trying to create a model to buffer rivers, lake and spring but sometimes I don't have some of my input (river, lake or spring). Is it possible to create a model with optional input ? How to do that ? (I don't have experience with Python).

Another question is:
2 - We work whith 5 computers and I want to share the model with others (We don't have server, every user has its own user name) How should I set the workspace and how to do that ?

Comment: Model is in toolbox and toolbox is portable. If you create a toolbox  and last copy and paste in wanted directory. Next if you don't create other traitment as buffer it's more simply to use the toolbox directly... but you can [read this tutorial for biginning](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/creating-tools-in-modelbuilder-tutorial.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question per question. You can use the [edit] button to remove your second question.